# Getting host IP in a container from the request generated by a container on same host

Tags: docker, go, docker-network

I have a goland reverse proxy server and want to differentiate between requests generated by another container on the same VM from requests coming from another host and only allow request generated on the same VM. I know this can be achieved by connecting all the containers to some network, but that's doesn't fit in my scenario.

When a request is generated from another container on the same VM, the request includes container (or network interface) IP as RemoteAddr which keeps changing when network is recreated.

When the request is made from another VM, it includes IP of the VM instead of the container. As per my understanding the request never leaves the VM when request is made from container on the VM to another container on the same VM and therefore it contains IP of the container instead of IP of the VM.

Is there a way that i could differentiate the requests coming from container from the same VM vs requests from another VM.

Comment: How about adding a request header to determine where the request comes from? So for that scenario, the proxy will check that header and decide if the request allowed.

Comment: Actually we are using a third party app that's making the request to this golang server container and I cannot modify the request header generated by that app unfortunately

Comment: If you're lucky, the app might be providing a unique user-agent (which is also a header).  It's not really "security" but it might fit for your uses